# Continuous function, Find f(1)=?

Tags: calculus

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function which can accept only rational values. If we know that $f(0)=2$, $f(1)=?$

I think it should be $2$ because of the continuity but I don't know how to prove it formally.

Comment: `which can accept only rational values` Do you mean "can ***take*** only rational values", maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f(1):=\alpha\ne 2$, then there is some irrational number $\eta$ in between $\alpha$ and $2$, and by Intermediate Value Theorem, $f(\gamma)=\eta$ for some $\gamma\in(0,1)$, this is a contradiction.

Comment: I’m not sure I understood the proof well enough. Isn’t f(γ) = η valid since the function maps to reals?

Comment: We specify $\eta$ first, but it is not sure at the beginning if this $\eta$ lies in the range of $f$, so it may not be necessarily $f(\gamma)=\eta$ for some $\gamma$. Of course it actually turns out to be the case because of the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: Yeah I understood that. But what I didn’t get is that what exactly happens if f(γ) is irrational for some γ?

Comment: Then it is a contradiction.

Comment: That’s what I’m not sure about. Isn’t it mapping to reals?

Comment: OP has written there the values only for rational numbers, not all real numbers.

Comment: Okay so the inputs may be all reals, but outputs are rationals?

Comment: Yes, this is the assumption of the question.

Comment: Oh okay thanks, I thought it was the other way round haha.